# Why does the PDF of CHIDistribution with 1 degree of freedom vanish at x=0

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, distribution

Both Wolfram Alpha and Mathematica on Raspberry give
`PDF[ChiDistribution[1],0] = 0` although the PDF is
`sqrt(2/π) e^(-x^2/2), x>0` and the limit would be 
`sqrt(2/π)`. Is this a bug or a feature? If a feature,
what makes the ChiDistribution differ from the
ExponentialDistribution with PDF e.g. `2 e^(-2 x), x>= 0` and `PDF[ExponentialDistribution[2],0] = 2`?

To be more precise: Why are the specifications different at x=0? Are there
any theoretical reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a feature, and the answer is in your own specifications for the two PDFs.  For the Chi, the range is strictly greater than zero.  For the exponential, it's greater than or equal to zero.  PDFs are always zero outside the specified range, hence your answer.

Comment: Admitted, no bug because it follows the definition. But then the questions is: **Why** are there **different** specifications? Any theoretical reasons?

Comment: @gammatester I suspect it's arbitrary, Wikipedia lists the support as [0,infinity).  Mathematically it shouldn't matter, since the only way to get a zero is to have the underlying Gaussian be exactly equal to it's mean, which happens with probability zero.